# how to resolve mismatch between PWM resolution and sensor resolution?

Tags: pwm, resolution

I have an application that uses a high resolution sensor. The actuation loop runs on this sensor's feedback. Thus, the PWM resolution is limiting my achievable resolution in the actuator's movement. This seems like a common enough problem. Is there any standard way to get around this?

One way would be to amp up the PWM resolution by using fractional delays or increasing PWM clock's frequency. But assuming I have done all this, is there any other way to get a better PWM resolution?

Comment: Does it have to be PWM? Could you use a high-resolution DAC? Will dithering help in this particular case?

Comment: I don't think there are many options. What is the actuator PWM is driving? Perhaps some heavier gearing will help?

Comment: I agree with @SpehroPefhany, if you've exhausted all other options and don't want to use a DAC, you could dither the PWM at a frequency that's higher than your actuator's response time.  If you wanted PWM halfway between two steps you would dither the lower and upper PWM steps at a high frequency, spending 50% of the time on each step (and so on.)